# How to Resize a .tif whilst retaining channel properties (transparency)

Tags: php, tiff, imagemagick-convert

Currently I am running this command on a CentOs Unix server with ImageMagick version 6.7.2-7.

```
convert Test.tif -channel All -separate -resize 50% -background none -alpha copy -combine Test10.tif
```

It is doing everything I need it to - but it is adding a white background to each of the Channels as shown here:
[the test file before and after the command as shown in Photoshop CS4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1AKV.jpg)

I have tried lots of different settings for alpha background etc but I cannot get it to retain the transparency on the RGB channels. [This is the test file if you want to check it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6XGr.jpg)

I don't know if it needs me to run this command and specify a profile - its so close to being right - it could be something very simple but I can't find anyone mentioning this specific issue with .tif?

Thanks in advance.

## UPDATED

[Outcome After the first suggestion by fmw42](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6XGr.jpg) - run on Windows 7 Professional Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-25 Q16 x64

Comment: The file you have provided for your test file is a white PNG (no transparency) not TIF. Please post a link to the TIF file.

Comment: @fmw42 - that would be StackOverflows attempt to process a transparent .tif ;) 
http://www.urbanwarfarestudios.co.uk/Test.tif

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me in Imagemagick 6.9.10.25 Q16 Mac OSX

```
convert -quiet \( test.tif[0] -channel alpha -negate +channel \) test.tif[1] -background none -layers merge -resize 50% test_result.tif
```

http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/tif_proc/test_resize.tif

The issue is that Imagemagick does not handle background transparency in TIF files as cleanly as it could. In Photoshop you have one layer with background transparency. But Imagemagick sees two layers. The first has transparency (but is the wrong polarity and needs to be inverted). It is full size. But the second layer also contains transparency and is not the full size of the first layer. So one has to negate the first layer, use -layers merge to composite the second over the first in the correct offset and then resize. Imagemagick references layers starting with index 0 as in [0].

Windows syntax is slightly different (remove the \s):

```
convert -quiet ( test.tif[0] -channel alpha -negate +channel ) test.tif[1] -background none -layers merge -resize 50% test_result.tif
```

If in a .bat file, you need to double the % to %%.

Comment: As you did it on Mac I tried it on my Windows 7 machine:
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-25 Q16 x64 2019-01-28

I have uploaded the result of your command - the file is the same except now the background is now black on all channels and shows as gold rather than white when all the channels are active in Photoshop if that makes sense?

For comparison my command when run on Windows gives the same result. Would this command only work with the channels in a certain order?

Comment: Also when I open your file - its the same as when I run your command with the black and gold showing when all channels are active?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. When I open the result of my processing in Photoshop, it looks fine -- just like your input when opened in Photoshop. Windows syntax is slightly different than my Unix syntax. I have added to my post above for the equivalent Windows command.

Comment: Your original image has both background transparency and an alpha channel. Imagemagick cannot handle both at the same time. I get two slightly different results if I do: `convert -quiet \( test.tif[0] -channel rgba -evaluate set 0 \) test.tif[1] -background none -layers merge -resize 50% x.tif` and
`convert -quiet \( test.tif[0] -channel alpha -negate +channel \) test.tif[1] -background none -layers merge -resize 50% x2.tif`

Comment: You can choose to use an alpha channel or background transparency when you write the output using `tiff:alpha=associated|unassociated|unspecified`. But you cannot specify both.

Comment: I also see a slight difference between those 2 commands. I posted an updated link to how the output looks in my Photoshop on the original question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6XGr.jpg  It shows what happens to the channels when I open your file/my file after running your commands.

Comment: As I mentioned before, Imagemagick cannot handle both at the same time. This was the best I could do. You could post a question or request on the Imagemagick Discourse server at https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/